# Is there a way to mount Google Drive on my local machine like what could be done in Colab?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

In Colab, the following code snippet is used for mounting Google Drive.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/test', force_remount=True)
```

And I'm wondering if it could work on my local machine. When implementing this locally, it says "no module named google", even after having executed `pip install google`.
Is there another package that should be installed, or it just cannot be achieved? I've searched for a while, but it seems that the only solution is to install Google Drive Desktop to give access to remote files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Although `google.colab` python library can be found [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools), this library is a collection of tools meant to work in conjunction with the Google Colab product.
- Indeed, Google Drive Desktop is your best option to "mount" your Google Drive to your local machine.
- Alternatively, there are several 3rd party Google Drive clients available.

Comment: It seems that Google Drive Desktop does not support Linux :(

Answer (score 0):

Use ocamlfuse.
Here are the step by step details: https://medium.com/@enthu.cutlet/how-to-mount-google-drive-on-linux-windows-systems-5ef4bff24288

Instead of mounting it to a home folder (named googledrive in tutorial), I suggest mounting it such that folder structure would be same for both colab and local machine. To do that:

- create your mounting folder at root (it's not a recommended practice but there is no harm). You need to use sudo. i.e at /, use sudo mkdir test
- then create MyDrive inside test.
- Chnage test or MyDrive owner to yourself: sudo chown <your username> MyDrive/
- Mount to MyDrive by: google-drive-ocamlfuse MyDrive/
- Enjoy!